# QSlQuery fails for MySQL select statement

Tags: mysql, qt

I have the following MySQL query used in my Qt application:

```
query.prepare(QString("SELECT productName, value, COUNT(value), SUM(value)"
                  "FROM tblmystock"
                  "WHERE time>=\'%1\' AND time<=\'%2\'"
                  "GROUP BY productName, value").arg(startDateTime, endDateTime));
```

I get the following error: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near'>='2012-04-24 00:00:00' AND time<='2012-04-24 23:59:59:59' GROUP BY productName' at line 1 QMYSQL: Unable to execute query`

Even when I try to bindValues, it fails with the same error.

But when I execute the same query on the MySQL prompt like below, it works fine:

```
mysql> SELECT productName, value, COUNT(value), SUM(value) FROM tblmystock WHERE time>='2012-04-24 00:00:00' AND time<='2012-04-25 23:59:59' GROUP BY productName, value;
```

Does anybody know a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

`time` is a reserved keyword. Use backticks to escape it. 
You can also use `between` instead of `<=` and `>=`

```
WHERE `time` between '2012-04-24 00:00:00' AND '2012-04-25 23:59:59'
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried your suggestion but I got the same error. I even tried to change time to trxnTime but no change!

Comment: @user1353283: Try replacing the escaped `\'` with `'`: `... WHERE time between '%1' and ...`

Comment: @jurgen d: still no help. I have noticed that the problem is with my QStrings startDateTime and endDateTime, because when i replace them with actual datetime, it works fine. This is the definition of them:void MyClass::myFunc(QString &sDate, QString &eDate)
{
    QString startDateTime = sDate + " 00:00:00"; //beginning of general report
    QString endDateTime = eDate + " 23:59:59"; //end of general report                                                                ...                                                                   }

Comment: What is the database definition of `time` column?

Comment: I just figured where the problem was; I had to put a  space " " before the where clause such that it ends up as " WHERE time>=\'%1\' AND time<=\'%2\'"
. Thanks